# Not able to integrate and test Jersey in my project

Tags: java, jersey

I'm able to test mkyong example http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-jersey-client/ of jersey using Get and Post methods in a separate project. But, when I try to integrate the same example in my project which is maven and using Struts framework too , it doesn't run. I've added all the dependencies in pom.xml and configured in web.xml

URL I'm passing is

```
http://localhost:8080/MyProject/restful/json/metallica/get
```

The error which I get is

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector$Pair.findSerializer(AnnotationIntrospector.java:1148)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.findSerializerFromAnnotation(BasicSerializerFactory.java:367)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:252)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:782)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:735)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:344)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:420)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:601)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:256)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1613)
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.writeTo(JacksonJsonProvider.java:520)
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.writeTo(JacksonProviderProxy.java:160)
```

Any ideas what is going on wrong?

Comment: Can you provide us with code and configuration.

Comment: I've added the same package as it is mentioned in the example.